# Не добавляется источник данных в проекте C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Учусь работе с БД из C# (VS 2013).
 Создал проект, форму, есть база на MS SQL SERVER 2014 Expess. 
 В VS на вкладке Источники данных добавляю - БД - Набор данных - Создать подключение -  Источник данных (Microsoft SQL Server, Поставщик данных (.NET для SQL Server) - Имя сервера localhost - Подключение к базе данных (видит все базы), выбираю необходимую мне. Проверить подключение - Проверка выполнена, при нажатии ОК выдает:

> "Не удается добавить подключение данных. Ссылка на объект не указывает
>   на экземпляр объекта"

В чем проблема?

Comment: Приложите скрин ошибки.

Comment: @ Ella Svetlaya Приложен...

Answer (score 4):

Проблему решил случайной мыслью. Сервер MS SQL 64-битный, а в версии VS установлено свойство компиляции AnyCPU. После изменения свойства на x64 все заработало!